# How we get username in firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

> In firebase, we create user with email and password by using createUserWithEmailAndPassword. But when we verify the token and get the firebase user, It returns some properties like email, userid, uid, name,etc. Here we just send the email and password then How we get the user name even we are not passing user name to firebase. I know this is silly one but I am not able to understand how it is working. Please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you try to access `firebase.auth().currentUser.displayName`, then it will log `undefined` as you never set the display name. You should update the name using `updateProfile` method after the user signs up.

```js
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword().then((userCred) => {
  const {user} = userCred
  user.updateProfile({displayName: "myNewName"}).then(() => {
    console.log("Name Updated")
    console.log(firebase.auth().currentUser.displayName)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if (user != null) {
    // Name, email address etc
    String name = user.getDisplayName();
    String email = user.getEmail();
}
```